# Should the word before a numeral be capitalized

Tags: numbers

If you type out *week 1* or *top 25 matchup*, would the word before the numeral be capitalised?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience this is very dependent on some pretty arbitrary conditions. The main arbitrary conditions being whether the noun being numbered is "important" or "established" or the title of something. But this is troublesome. Take for example "step 1". That's a fine use. But if you talked about the first step of Alcoholics Anonymous (We admitted we were powerless over alcohol), then you might write "Step 1", capitalising the S.

I'm not exactly sure what the criteria might be, but I think one of the most accepted usages of capitalisation would be for titles.

"page 10", but "Chapter 10" may be another case. It all depends and I'm not in a position to give a full list of criteria. Hopefully someone else can help.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. I've seen it written in both senses, but it is context-dependent.

(e.g.) The year 1969 was a good year for wine.

Comment: Please explain *how* it is context-dependent.